# Why does my stacked column chart print incorrect x axis labels?

Tags: vb.net, charts

A bit of information:

I would like to populate a stacked column chart with transactions from the last 12 months.
Every column should be a month in the year and the transactions are of course stacked on top of each other.

At the moment, I just have a test document where I pull some data from. I first tried to directly put the data (from the csv) in the chart, but that just resulted in multiple columns with the multiple duplicate x axis label and nothing stacked.

I did some digging and found this solution. unfortunately, the result is not what I'm looking for. The transactions are stacked but the x axis labels are incorrect

At the moment I have

```
    Dim rowsTra() As String = File.ReadAllLines(".\data\transactions.csv")
    Dim traVal() As String
    Dim preYear As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    Dim dtTest As DataTable = New DataTable
    dtTest.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(Double))
    dtTest.Columns.Add("col2", GetType(String))
    dtTest.Columns.Add("col3", GetType(String))

    For i As Integer = 0 To rowsTra.Length - 1 Step +1                                      ' Looping through all transactions
        traVal = rowsTra(j).ToString().Split(",")
        Dim traDate As String = Convert.ToDateTime(traVal(1))
        If (traDate >= preYear) Then                                                        ' Check if date is not older than 1 year
            Dim conMonth As Date = CDate(traVal(1))
            Dim month = conMonth.ToString("MMM yyyy")
            dtTest.Rows.Add(traVal(6), month, traVal(4))
        Else
            i = rowsTra.Length - 1                                                          ' Quit loop if year ends (will only work if csv is chronological
        End If
        j += 1
    Next

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dtTest)
    dv.Sort = "col2 asc"

    chTrend.Series.Clear()
    chTrend.Titles.Clear()                                                             ' Clear
    chTrend.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "col3", "col2", "col1", "Label=col1")                    ' Populate chart

    For Each cs As Series In chTrend.Series                                                 ' Stack values
        cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
    Next
```

By using this csv file I get this result:

```
Account 1,19 Dec 2021,Man 1,Cat 1,Subcat 1,test,5
Account 2,01 Dec 2021,Man 2,Cat 2,Subcat 2,test,10
Account 5,01 Nov 2021,Man 4,Cat 2,Subcat 2,test,10
Account 4,27 Oct 2021,Man 4,Cat 4,Subcat 4,test,20
Account 3,10 Oct 2021,Man 3,Cat 3,Subcat 3,test,15
Account 1,03 Sep 2020,Man 1,Cat 1,Subcat 1,test,25
           = col2                  =col3         =col1
```

[image]

Why would it in this case add 4 transactions under the "Dec 2021" when only 2 transactions actually are?
I've noticed that when I change the 3rd listed transaction to another Subcat, all transactions fall under Dec 2021.

Ive also tried to just give col2 in dtTest the Date type but this just gave an even weirder chart and I'm not sure how to then format the date to "MMM yyyy". This is my reason to move from datetime to string

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for the input. Sorry for the messy code, still learning.

Comment: Alright, so I might have figured out a solution but I'm not sure if it's viable. I assume it is printing out an incorrect chart because for some months not all existing subcategories are given a value. Is there an efficient way to generate all existing subcategories for each month or is it best to just store the subcategories separately and loop through them to create the needed rows in the dataTable?

Answer (score 1):

So I did some experimenting myself and I believe I found "A" solution to my problem.

I'm sharing it, since it might be to helpful to someone in the future.
In the end I came up with this solution.

It not only stacks correctly by adding the extra rows needed (as mentioned in my comment), but also adds up values from already existing categories.

This is something that I was aiming for did not mention in my original question.

I'm definitely not saying this is the best solution and I know it can cause some performance issues with scalability. I'd go so far as to say it might even be just spaghetti code so I'd love to see someone with more experience find a more optimal solution to this problem.

```
Dim rowsTra() As String = File.ReadAllLines(".\transactions.csv")
    Dim traVal() As String
    Dim strCat As String = ""
    Dim strDate As String = ""
    Dim preYear As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)                                     ' Start date for all visible transactions in chart
    Dim dtTrend As DataTable = New DataTable
    dtTrend.Columns.Add("outflow", GetType(Double))                                         ' Columns for DataTable
    dtTrend.Columns.Add("date", GetType(String))
    dtTrend.Columns.Add("category", GetType(String))
    Dim valExist As Boolean
    Dim l As Integer = 0 'l
    Dim m As Integer = 0 'm

    For i As Integer = 0 To rowsTra.Length - 1 Step +1                                      ' Loop all transactions to add to DataTable and list all dates and categories
        traVal = rowsTra(l).ToString().Split(",")
        Dim traDate As String = Convert.ToDateTime(traVal(1))
        Dim traMonth = CDate(traVal(1)).ToString("MMM yyyy")                                ' Convert to Month Year
        If (traDate >= preYear) Then                                                        ' Check if date is not older than 1 year
            If dtTrend.Rows.Count = 0 Then                                                  ' First transaction loop
                dtTrend.Rows.Add(traVal(6), traMonth, traVal(4))                            ' Add row to DataTable in order "outflow/date/category"
            Else                                                                            ' If not first transaction
                m = 0
                valExist = False                                                            ' Reset valExist to false
                While m < dtTrend.Rows.Count                                                ' Loop DataTable, used to add outflow to existing categories
                    If dtTrend.Rows(m)(1).ToString = traMonth And dtTrend.Rows(m)(2) = traVal(4) Then   ' Check if date and category match between DataTable and Transactions 
                        dtTrend.Rows(m)(0) = dtTrend.Rows(m)(0) + traVal(6)                 ' Add outflow to existing DataTable row
                        m = dtTrend.Rows.Count
                        valExist = True
                    End If
                    m += 1
                End While

                If valExist = False Then                                                    ' If combo of date and subcategory does not exist:
                    dtTrend.Rows.Add(traVal(6), traMonth, traVal(4))                        ' Add new line to DataTable
                End If
            End If

            If strCat = "" Then                                                             ' If string has no value (first loop). Used to create list of subcategories
                strCat = traVal(4)
            ElseIf strCat.Contains(traVal(4)) Then                                          ' Check if category already exist in the string
            Else
                strCat = strCat + "," + traVal(4)
            End If
            If strDate = "" Then                                                            ' Ditto about but for Date
                strDate = traMonth
            ElseIf strDate.Contains(traMonth) Then
            Else
                strDate = strDate + "," + traMonth
            End If
        Else
            i = rowsTra.Length - 1                                                          ' Quit loop if year ends (will only work if csv is chronological
        End If
        l += 1
    Next

    Dim arrCat() As String = strCat.Split(",")                                              ' Split string to use in array
    Dim arrDate() As String = strDate.Split(",")
    Dim tfMatch As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To arrCat.Length - 1 Step +1                                       ' Loop existing categories, used to add non existing row
        For j As Integer = 0 To arrDate.Length - 1 Step +1                                  ' Loop existing dates, rows need to be added to get full series
            Dim dtRows = dtTrend.Rows.Count
            For k As Integer = 0 To dtRows - 1                                              ' Loop through original DataTable values
                If dtTrend.Rows(k)(1) = arrDate(j) And dtTrend.Rows(k)(2) = arrCat(i) Then  ' Check if date and categorys match anywhere in the DataTable
                    tfMatch = True
                End If
            Next
            If tfMatch = True Then                                                          ' If match, reset and search with next date
                tfMatch = False
            Else
                dtTrend.Rows.Add(0, arrDate(j), arrCat(i))                                  ' If no match, add as new row in DataTable
                tfMatch = False                                                             ' Reset, moving to next category
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dtTrend)
    dv.Sort = "date desc"

    chTrend.Series.Clear()                                                                  ' Clear chart before fill so no exceptions are generated
    chTrend.Titles.Clear()
    chTrend.DataManipulator.FilterSetEmptyPoints = True                                     ' Filter to get correct stack
    chTrend.DataManipulator.FilterMatchedPoints = True
    chTrend.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "category", "date", "outflow", "Label=outflow")          ' Populate chart

    For Each cs As Series In chTrend.Series                                                 ' Removes labels of newly added rows with value "0"
        chTrend.DataManipulator.Filter(DataVisualization.Charting.CompareMethod.EqualTo, 0, cs)   'Compare if equal to zero, filter out
        cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn                                        ' Chart type
        'Dim dpcp As DataPointCustomProperties = New DataPointCustomProperties
    Next
```